# Parallelogram banner expands on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make one banner with 4 images inside that expands on hover and allows the user to click on the buttons inside. The banner should be a square and parallelogram shaped on the inside.

This is what I got so far (http://jsbin.com/tujehatofi/1/watch?html,css,output):

I can't seem to get the sides to be shaped properly and the text is always underneath the image. Please help!

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean by parallelogram. A rectangle is a valid parallelogram I guess.

Comment: it looks pretty cool, so what's wrong? you can't get the edges of the shapes to have pointed corners? can't see any text on your jsbin

Comment: @joe https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/ they have an example there.  To have text inside, use position: relative along with z-index and it should work quite well.

Comment: @AlanSutherland yeah, I want the edges to have pointed corners, but I don't know how.

Comment: @samayres1992 I tried using z-index with relative to make the text go in front, but its not working...it still stays behind the image

Comment: Think you might be able to create the pointed edges using :before and :after pseudo elements